# SIGNALs are not working in PySide

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, pyside, qtgui, qtcore

I wrote a simple application in Python and PySide. When I run it, SIGNALs are not working.
The application starts without errors.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        dial = QDial()
        dial.setNotchesVisible(True)

        spinbox = QSpinBox()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(dial)
        layout.addWidget(spinbox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(dial, SIGNAL("valueChaged(int)"), spinbox.setValue)
        self.connect(spinbox, SIGNAL("valueChaged(int)"), dial.setValue)

        self.setWindowTitle("Signals and Slots")
    # END def __init__
# END class Form

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
# END def main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# END if
```

I am using:

Pyside 1.2.2;
Python 2.7.6;
OS Centos; Windows 7

I am running the application with:

Sublime Text 3 and Eclipse Luna;

How can I make SIGNALs working?

Comment: Btw. With new style signal syntax `dial.valueChanged.connect(spinbox.setValue)` you would have got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signal name is incorrect;

**Incorrect :**

```
valueChaged (int)
```

**[Correct](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) :**

```
valueChanged (int)
```

Test it, work fine;

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class QFormDialog (QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(QFormDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myQial = QDial()
        self.myQSpinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.myQHBoxLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.myQial.setNotchesVisible(True)
        self.myQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQial)
        self.myQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQSpinbox)
        self.setLayout(self.myQHBoxLayout)
        self.connect(self.myQial,     SIGNAL('valueChanged(int)'), self.myQSpinbox.setValue)
        self.connect(self.myQSpinbox, SIGNAL('valueChanged(int)'), self.myQial.setValue)
        self.setWindowTitle('Signals and Slots')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQFormDialog = QFormDialog()
    myQFormDialog.show()
    myQApplication.exec_()
```

Note : PyQt4 & PySide is same way to implemented.